# Share button inside MPMovieController instance

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

Can you share (e.g. facebook, twitte, etc.) from inside a movie player instance?[image: vimeo screenshot]

The intention is to replicate this functionality (see attached) while watching a video on a iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Share button is on the top of the movie player in the z plain. Therefore, of course you could do it by adding a `SubView`.